# How to change VSCode terminal bold text color?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, colors

In macOS Terminal app there is a setting which allows to customize bold text color:

[image]

Then, for example, `man` output would look like this:

[image]

How to achieve the same result in VSCode embedded terminal? Manipulation with VSCode terminal setting `Draw bold text in bright colors` doesn't seem to work, even if I tweak all bright colors to red in `Settins.json`:

[image]

Still yields:

[image]